# check if object has been updated mongoid 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid, mongoid3

```
1.9.3p448 :014 > l.reload
 => #<Lesson _id: 527246641d41c81d14000006, title: "ola"> 
1.9.3p448 :015 > l.changed?
 => false 
1.9.3p448 :016 > l.changes
 => {} 
1.9.3p448 :017 > l.previous_changes
 => {"title"=>["olaaaaa", "ola"]} 
1.9.3p448 :018 > l.changed?
 => false 
1.9.3p448 :019 > l.update_attributes(title: "olaaa")
 => true 
1.9.3p448 :020 > l.changes
 => {} 
1.9.3p448 :021 > l.changed?
 => false
```

I have updated the attribute `"title"` but when I try `l.changed?` I get `false`.

I know the `new_record?` method, to know if a object is a new object but I need to know if a object is updated.

**I would like to know, how can I know if a object has been updated with mongoid 3.x?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reload, save, update, the changes are moved to previous_changes. You also have access to the changes on callbacks, otherwise you will have to use `previous_changes` .
Thats by design, to be consistent with ActiveRecord.